# Flask SQLAlchemy import DB import

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask with SQLAlchemy, after set all configuration setting I got db import error on model.

**ImportError: cannot import name 'db'**

my main app **__init__**

```
from flask_api import FlaskAPI
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask import request

from app.test.controllers import test


def create_app(config_name):
    app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    from app.test.controllers import test
    app.register_blueprint(test)
```

my controller and model in app/test/test.py and model.py

**test.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, redirect, url_for
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from app.test.model import TestModel

test = Blueprint('test', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v1')


@test.route('/test/store', methods=['POST'])
def store():
    return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

my **model.py**

```
from app import db

class TestModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_profiles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False)
    email= db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False)


    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name, self.email)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Flask factory method so initialize SqlAlchemy in your model and import it to your __init__.py file

So model.py becomes

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy    
db = SQLAlchemy()

class TestModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_profiles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False)
    email= db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False)


    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name, self.email)
```

Then in __init__.py it becomes

```
from flask_api import FlaskAPI
from model import db
import os
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask import request

from app.test.controllers import test


def create_app(config_name):
    app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
    db.init_app(app)
    from app.test.controllers import test
    app.register_blueprint(test)
```

Comment: hi, so if there is multiple models. how can i import db

Comment: i want single __init__ file which creates the db instance and then any model can access it.

Comment: If you want multiple model files, then you can put them a package(lets call the package models) and in the __init__.py file of the models package, you create the db object and import it where ever its needed.